# asp.net gridview edit mode index

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview which is populated via a sql data source with the SELECT command: `Select * FROM myTable`

When the page is first loaded that displays every record in the table.

The gridview has an Edit button for each row and when the user clicks the row I want to update the gridview to display only that result in the gridview so I change the SELECT command of the sql data source to `SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE ID = currentEditRow`

That works except for one issue, when editing any other row but the first, the Update and Cancel buttons do not show up on the row. It is like is not in edit mode.

Any idea why that is?

Code:

```
 protected void gvResults_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
        {
            gvResults.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
            SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM [myTable] WHERE ID = '" + ID + "'";
        }
```

Comment: You must show the problem relevant code

Comment: Added but not much more than what I have mentioned. I believe it is something to do with postback and after the gridview only displays the one record, it still has the EditIndex value of when the gridview had multiple rows.

Comment: Basically after the gridview only shows one record the editIdex will always be 0 (because there is only row returned)

Comment: @sd_dracula I think you can write the codes after right-click datasource. writing extra code to code behind might have caused the error.

Comment: Can you explain that again please

Comment: I think you just want to use a gvGridView.DataBind(); You will want to remove the sqldatasource1.SelectCommand. This should put each row into edit mode once clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GridView will bind data again automatically when you set a new command to `SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand`. This made it returns to start mode (Display read-only data with Edit button in GridView).

Otherwise, you trick it as my sample code below ...

This is my GridView binding data with SqlDataSource1, has DataKey names "code". There are three event handlings to implement: **OnRowEditing, OnSelectedIndexChanged and OnRowCancelingEdit.**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
    DataKeyNames="code" 
    OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" 
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" 
    OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="std_room_id" HeaderText="Room ID" SortExpression="std_room_id" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="booking_name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="booking_name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="course_id" HeaderText="Course" SortExpression="course_id" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="course_period" HeaderText="Period" SortExpression="course_period" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="start_date" HeaderText="Start Date" SortExpression="start_date" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="end_date" HeaderText="End Date" SortExpression="end_date" />
        <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="approved" HeaderText="Approved" SortExpression="approved" />
        <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="true" SelectText="Edit"/>
        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true" Visible="false"/>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [BookingRoom]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    </div>
```

I have two CommandFields: SelectButton to click when user want open Edit Mode, and the second CommandField for display Update and Cancel buttons.

And this is my code-behide

```
protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.Columns[7].Visible = false;
}

protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string code = GridView1.DataKeys[GridView1.SelectedIndex].Value.ToString();
    SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM [BookingRoom] WHERE code = '" + code + "'";

    GridView1.Columns[8].Visible = true;
    GridView1.SetEditRow(0);
}

protected void GridView1_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.Columns[7].Visible = true;
    GridView1.Columns[8].Visible = false;
}
```

I tricked it by show the SelectButton (display text as "Edit") in GridView with all loaded data in start mode. When user selects the row by clicking the SelectButton, it will start to do the steps in **GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged** which try to display only the selected row in GridView and set Edit Mode to that row togather with displaying the second CommandField (Update and Cancel buttons).

To set Edit Mode by this line `GridView1.SetEditRow(0);`, it will do the step in **GridView1_RowEditing** which try to hide the SelectButton.

Final, you have to handle the cancling Edit Mode as in **GridView1_RowCancelingEdit** which try to display the SelectButton, and hide the Update and Cancel buttons.

I access those two CommandFields by their column index according to my columns in GridView: column index of Select button is 7 and column index of Update and Cancel buttons is 8

Comment: Ok I see what you're trying to do and it sounds like a good idea. But whenever I hit Select on a row which is not the first one (index 0) it always selects the data from row 0.

Comment: You have to check if the **ID** you pass to the query is correct. Put breakpoint at this line **SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM [myTable] WHERE ID = '" + ID + "'";** and check the ID value.

Comment: In your **gvResults_SelectedIndexChanged** method, you should get the correct selected row index from `gvResults.SelectedIndex` and if you set `DataKeyNames="ID"` in GridView as I did, then you should also get the correct ID by this code **`string ID = gvResults.DataKeys[gvResults.SelectedIndex].Value.ToString();`** (implemented in **gvResults_SelectedIndexChanged** method)

Comment: Ok so the ID comes back good, I have checked it with breakpoints but it seems that the problem is with this line: `gvResults.SetEditRow(0);` in the SelectedIndexChanged. if I comment it out the correct ID gets selected, if I leave it in then it always selects and puts the first row from the full gridview into edit mode.

Comment: Strange, that doesn't happen to me, after set new command to **SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand** you should have only the selected row in GridView, then **GridView1.SetEditRow(0)** shouldn't make any effect to queryed data. Could you please provide me the full code you have now?

Comment: Ok I had forgotten to add the equivalent of yours DataKeyNames="code" and now that I have, it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to interchange the two line of codes:

```
protected void gvResults_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
     SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM [myTable] WHERE ID = '" + ID + "'";
     gvResults.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;   
}
```